# Android Support Repository does not display in Android sdk manager

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to install `Android Support Repository` package to my application and run it successfully.
But the repository is not displaying in the sdk manager.

How can I add `Android Support Repository` inside the sdk manager?

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me just now, support repository 27.0.0 isn't showing in the standalone SDK manager. Have you tried updating it directly from the AS launch menu, without shutting down AS and without launching the standalone SDK manager?